# getting the error : recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[Here is the logcat messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln6bh.png)This is main activity and i'm getting error at var userData = snaps.getValue(Users::class.java) and No adapter attached; skipping layout

```
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    userRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    userRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    userRecyclerView.hasFixedSize()
    userList = arrayListOf<Users>()
    getUserList()

    private fun getUserList() {
    dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
    dbref.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear()
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                for (snaps in snapshot.children){
                    var userData = snaps.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    userList.add(userData!!)
                }
                val mAdapter = adapter(userList)
                userRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }
    })
}
```

This is data class:

```
    class Users (
    var userId :String? =null,
    var password :String? =null
    )
```

This is the adapter class:

```
class adapter(private val userList:ArrayList<Users>)
:RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.ViewHolder>(){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val itemView =LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.users,parent,false)
    return ViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = userList[position]
    holder.userID.text =current.userId
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}
class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val userID :TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.userTv)
}
}
```

help me :(..................................
.......................................
............................................

Comment: "var userData = snaps.getValue(Users::class.java)"

Have you checked the contents of `snaps` that it contains a User?
What is the actual error you are receiving? - You can copy from inside logcat and attach it to your question in order to give more information to those willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cause of your problem, but you don't need to assign adapter in getUserList(). Instead, you can do it right where you assign a LayoutManager. But to answer your question, I need more details about your error, like log messages.

Comment: i have tried that too , but it's not working. I have added a image of logcat messages

Comment: Your problem is deserialisation of "User". You receive json from server. In order to add a user in your list, you have to deserialise it from json. It's very easy actually. There are many libs for deserialization like Gson, Moshi and kotlin serialization

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem :

```
var userData = snaps.getValue(Users::class.java)
userList.add(userData!!)
```

you're adding a string to a list of type Users.

Comment: but in Users type ,there are string values which are being stored

Comment: Add a constructor in the Users class with 2 variables you've defined as parameters. The list you're creating is of type Users so you have to add a Users object to the list not Strings

Comment: In java you would say `Users user = new User(userID, password); Userlist.add(user);`

Answer (score 0):

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

The adapter is the way in which we get the list of items into the recycler view. If there is no adapter then there are no items and there is nothing to layout.

It's been a while since I used a recycler view, but I seem to remember this was a warning in logcat simply telling you that its jumped over the layout routine of the recycler view because there are no items to layout.

If you attach the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged`, then you will force the recycler view to run the layout routine, now that there are items to display.

```kotlin
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userList.clear()
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                for (snaps in snapshot.children){
                    var userData = snaps.getValue(Users::class.java)
                    userList.add(userData!!)
                }
                val mAdapter = adapter(userList)
                userRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
```